MimeKit SMTP Client - exclude recipients in specific domain
I am working on a SMTP sender application and I already went through many options but I still can't find solution.
Problem
I have a test message where in the emil message, I have some TO and CC recipients:
From: Sender Name <mailto:sender@example.com>
Date: Tue, 05 Nov 2024 14:01:23 +0100
Subject: Test Email Subject
Message-Id: \<49V3X5UIJOU4.CGAE9Q23ZQUK@laptop\>
To: Recipient 1 <mailto:recipient1@example.com>, Recipient 2 <mailto:recipient2@exclude.com>
Cc: CC Recipient 1 <mailto:ccrecipient1@example.com>, CC Recipient 2
<mailto:ccrecipient2@exclude.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

This is a test email body. It contains some sample text.

I am sending it using following code:
public void SendMessage(string emlFilePath, List <string> domainsToExclude) 
{
    // Load message EML file
    MimeMessage message;

    using(var stream = File.OpenRead(emlFilePath)) 
    {
        message = MimeMessage.Load(stream);
    }

    using(var client = new SmtpClient(new ProtocolLogger(Console.OpenStandardOutput()))) 
    {
        client.Connect("smtp_server", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
        client.Authenticate("user", "pass");

        // Send message eml
        client.Send(message);
 
        client.Disconnect(true);
    }
}

I want to exclude domain exclude.com in RCP TO communications BUT I want to keep it in the message body (I want to remove it from envelope) but no matter what I will do I always see it in communication:
C: MAIL FROM:<sender@example.com> SIZE=416
C: RCPT TO:<recipient1@example.com>
C: RCPT TO:<ccrecipient1@example.com>
C: RCPT TO:<ccrecipient2@exclude.com>   - **REMOVE**
S: 250 2.1.0 Ok
S: 250 2.1.0 Ok
S: 250 2.1.0 Ok
S: 250 2.1.0 Ok
C: DATA
S: 354 Go ahead
C: From: Sender Name <sender@example.com>
C: Date: Tue, 05 Nov 2024 14:43:40 +0100
C: Subject: Test Email Subject

Any idea ? Maybe I should use a different library?
I tried to load the message collect all recipients and remove all from exclude.com domain but that didn't work. It works only if I will remove them from message body but in this case they wont be visible in Outlook client etc.

Don't include in the to list by not adding to To collection of the Message: the whole point of that property is to be on the to list and to be sent to those addresses. I doubt any SMTP client will do anything else makes no sense ("send to an address but don't"!).

Change your code to this:
public void SendMessage(string emlFilePath, List <string> domainsToExclude) 
{
    // Load message EML file
    MimeMessage message;

    using(var stream = File.OpenRead(emlFilePath)) 
    {
        message = MimeMessage.Load(stream);
    }

    var sender = message.Sender ?? message.From.Mailboxes.First ();
    var recipients = message.GetRecipients(true).Where(mailbox => !domainsToExclude.Contains(mailbox.Domain));

    using(var client = new SmtpClient(new ProtocolLogger(Console.OpenStandardOutput()))) 
    {
        client.Connect("smtp_server", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
        client.Authenticate("user", "pass");

        // Send message eml
        client.Send(message, sender, recipients);
 
        client.Disconnect(true);
    }
}

